# Laravel kyslik/column-sortable Sort Nested related table

Tags: php, laravel-5

i use `kyslik/column-sortable` in laravel 5.1

```
model1= product 

belongsTo price_product

model2= price_product

belongsTo discount

model3=discount
```

sort in list of product

```
@sortablelink('price_product.discount.off', 'off')
```

> ErrorException in SortableLink.php line 102: Invalid sort argument